# Two full 48-gallon tanks begin draining at t = 0.

Tags: calculus

Two full $48$-gallon tanks begin draining at $t = 0$. Tank Alpha's volume is changing 
at a constant rate of $-\frac{16}{5} \frac{\text{gallons}}{\text{min}}$. The rate at which Tank Bravo's volume is 
changing is given by: $$r(t)=-\frac1{3t}-1\;\; \frac{\text{gallons}}{\text{min}}$$

a) How much water is in each tank after $5$ minutes?

b) Which tub drains first? How do you know?

Comment: It would appear that Tank Bravo drains instantaneously, given the infinite rate of drain at $t=0$.

Comment: Can you answer a for tank Alpha?  Can you say when Alpha is empty?  These are algebra, not calculus.  For Bravo, $r(t)$ is $\frac {dv}{dt}$, so if $v(t)$ is the volume in Bravo at time $t$ you have $v(t)=48+\int_0^t r(s)ds$

Comment: @RossMillikan I think form the original it was actually $$r(t)=-\frac1{3}t-1\;\; \frac{\text{gallons}}{\text{min}}$$ Can you change it? I tried editing but it doesn't work, probably because I already edited this post.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a rate, remember that taking the integral of that will give you the change in value. This can be modeled as:

$$\text{change in some value}=\int \text{rate of change of that value } d\zeta$$

You may have seen this commonly done in things like displacement, where you have:

$$\text{displacement}=\int v\; dt$$

This is because the velocity is the *rate* at which the position is moving.

Now for your question, let's go through each part.

a) First of all, remember that I said that the integral is the *change* in the value. It doesn't give you the absolute value. So for example, if I get a displacement of $5$ from $t=0$ to $t=5$, it means that my position changed by $5$. If my original position (at $t=0$) was $27$, then my new position at $t=0$ is $27+5=32$. Keep that in mind when we do this.

We are asked to get how much water was in the tanks. The first tank is pretty easy - it goes down at a rate of $\frac{16}{5}\; \frac{\text{gallons}}{\text{minute}}$. Even without calculus, we can find this out easily. But with calculus, we will model it as:

$$\text{change in volume of water}=\int_0^5 \left(-\frac{16}{5}\right) dt$$

Once again, that's the change not value. That's how much water was added to or reduced from the original. So we will need to add the original value to find the **value** after 5 minutes:

$$\text{volume of water}=48+\int_0^5 \left(-\frac{16}{5}\right) dt$$

This will give us the value after $5$ minutes. This is easy to integrate; very simply:

$$\int_0^5 \left(-\frac{16}{5}\right) dt=-\frac{16}{5}t\;\Biggr|_{t=0}^{t=5}=-16-0=-16$$

This is telling us that the volume was lowered by $16$ gallons. Hence the actual value after 5 minutes for that tank is:

$$\text{volume of water}=48-16=32 \text{ gallons}$$

Now for the next tank (Tank Bravo), the integral is a little more complicated (but still easy!). We have the change given by a function. As you may have guessed, the volume after 5 minutes will be:

$$\text{volume of water}=48+\int_0^5 \left(-\frac1{3}t-1\right) dt$$

Integrate this very quickly:

$$\int_0^5 \left(-\frac1{3}t-1\right) dt=-\frac1{6}t^2-t\; \Biggr|_{t=0}^{t=5}=-\frac{25}{6}-5-0=-\frac{55}{6}$$

And so, the value after $5$ minutes will be:

$$\text{volume of water}=48-\frac{55}{6}=38\frac{5}{6} \text{ gallons}$$

And that's all to it!

b) This is linked to the first problem. To know this, we need to know the amounts of each tank at some time $t$ and finds out for which it is equal to $0$ earliest.

For Tank Alpha, we said:

$$V=48+\int_0^t \left(-\frac{16}{5}\right) dt$$

So at any time $t$, the volume is:

$$V=48+\int_0^5 \left(-\frac{16}{5}\right) dt=48+\left(-\frac{16}{5}t\;\Biggr|_{t=0}^{t=t}\right)=48-\frac{16}{5}t$$

Thus, the volume is equal to $0$ at time:

$$V=0=48-\frac{16}{5}t$$

$$\therefore t=15\text{ min}$$

Now for the second tank, same procedure:

$$V=48+\int_0^t \left(-\frac1{3}t-1\right) dt$$

$$V=48+\left(-\frac1{6}t^2-t\; \Biggr|_{t=0}^{t=t}\right)=48-\frac1{6}t^2-t$$

Solve when $V=0$, either by quadratic formula or graphing or whatever and you get:
$$\therefore t\approx 14.2337\text{ min}$$

At any rate, this ones takes the least amount of time and thus drains fastest. Tank Bravo is the answer.